# How to make a final render look like the viewport materials shading?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine

I’ve got a character I’m working on. She looks exactly like I need her to be in the final animation in the viewport display, which I believe is a material preview with studio lighting.

When I go to render in Cycles, it takes on a totally different look. Obviously, the lighting and sampling are an issue, and I think, it needs a different HDRI. But there’s got to be a simpler way to render what I’m seeing.

Is there a workflow that someone can share that shows settings to help mirror exactly what’s going on in the viewport? I’ve attached a couple of samples.

Any direction would be appreciated:
[image]

Comment: [This Tutorial](https://youtu.be/6HIqF_MSnvU) will get you most of the way there.  Upshot: Use the same HDRIs and configure the render engine appropriately.  (Use EEVEE for render.)

Comment: THIS is the answer. So excellent. Thanks!

Comment: This is the answer to the question! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HIqF_MSnvU&list=WL&index=1

Answer (score 0):

If you want what you see in the viewport, do a viewport render.  From the 3D viewport's menus, view->viewport render image or viewport render animation.  This isn't a Cycles render, but it is exactly what you see in the viewport, and you say that is exactly what you want.