Using default .sl files at final Blender render
I want to use viewport shading tab studio lights at material viewport and final render (not viewport render). How can I do this?
P.S. Also, where I can find "studio lightning setup defult". At the folder I can only see five files, not six as at blender (plus no this name).




From this

To this


This BSE post may help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/252265, I also recommend using the 'viewport render' feature.
